# Output all possible combinations of numbers and letters in java

Tags: java

*I know a ton of similar questions already exist, but none of them solve my question*

Given an array of characters, I want to be able to
I want to generate a list of all possible combinations with those characters, of a specific length. And for every item in the list, I want to write it to a separate line in an output file.
Note that this code should be intended for use with **large** sets of numbers. (I want to use it on a data set of characters 36 long and want to generate a 32 long string) I know that there are 6.3340286662e+49 possible answers and want this function to generate *all of them*.
Here is some example input/ output:
input:
`int[] a ={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'};

calc(a,32);`

output file:

```
457abe9e7d27439681d62f4e0de1f5e1  
4adaw435kj546bjk34k4j234kj23f7t3  
awdf5e13h4kj546j43k13i3kj24b32hj
12ibj3jk2b4kj23b4kj23b432kjb4uui
etc..
```

I don't really know how I should structure the algorithm
This is my code so far, I know it is not much, i'll be appending more code as I work on it:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;

public class generator {
    public static void gen(int[] i, int l) {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("out.txt");
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
        //printWriter.print("Some String");
        boolean gotAll = false;
        Random rand = new Random();
        while (!gotAll) {
            String newStr = "";
            //not the best way to algorithmically get all possible outcomes
            for (int y = 0; y < l; y++) {
                //randomly generating characters from array
                newStr += i[rand.nextInt(i.length)];
            }
            //need to check for duplicate generation
            printWriter.println(newStr);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] i = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'};
        try {
            gen(i, 32);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Right the best way I can think of getting all the possible outcomes is to keep randomly generating numbers until all of them are found. This is obviously very time and resource intensive (which the solution will inevitably be).

Comment: But you haven’t tried anything, there is no trace of an algorithm in your code! This is basically a request for us to come up with an algorithm and write it for you. Please show at least some effort.

Comment: Well yeah the problem is I don't know how I should start writing the algorithm, I'm working on it now and will update my question

Comment: "there are 6.3340286662e+49 possible answers and want this function to generate all of them": you will need a lot of patience.

Comment: I've edited my question to include a *very* rudimentary solution, it just generates random numbers to form a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class A
{
    private static char[] alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2'};
    private static StringBuilder partialSolution = new StringBuilder();
    private static void bt(int maxIndex, int index)
    {
    if( index == maxIndex )
        {
            String solution = partialSolution.toString();
            System.out.println(solution);
        }
    else
        {
        for(char c: alphabet)
            {
                // Extend partial solution
                partialSolution.append(c);

                bt(maxIndex, index+1);
                final int lastCharIndex = partialSolution.length()-1;

                // Backtrack
                partialSolution.deleteCharAt(lastCharIndex);
            }
        }
    }
    private static void btCaller(int maxIndex)
    {
        bt(maxIndex, 0);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        btCaller(3);
    }
}
```

This can be done trivially with [Backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).
You can rest assured that you will not live enough to see [this end](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=36%5E32+nano+seconds+in+years). ;D

Comment: Is it possible to make this function non-recursive?

Comment: Yes. You could use a stack of int to store index (simulating the OS stack) or you could use a mapping between the elements in {0, 1, ..., b^n-1}, where b is your alphabet size and n is the maxIndex, and  every solution.